# Replace variables from text with corresponding values

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, preg-match

Let say I have the following string which I want to send as an email to a customer.

```
"Hello Mr/Mrs {{Name}}. You have subscribed for {{Service}} at {{Date}}."
```

And I have an array with the values that should be replaced

```
array(
    'Name' => $customerName, //or string
    'Service' => $serviceName, //or string
    'Date' => '2015-06-06'
);
```

I can find all strings between {{..}} with this:

```
preg_match_all('/\{{(.*?)\}}/',$a,$match);
```

where $match is an array with values, But I need to replace every match with a corresponding value from an array with values

**Note that the array with values contains a lot more values and the number of items in it or the keys sequence is not relevant to number of matches in string.**

Comment: As an alternative you can use an existing template engine which already does this. Or use a library that sends mail and accepts variables of the sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback` and pass the array with the help of `use` to the callback function:

```
$s = "Hello Mr/Mrs {{Name}}. You have subscribed for {{Service}} at {{Date}} {{I_DONT_KNOW_IT}}.";
$arr = array(
    'Name' => "customerName", //or string
    'Service' => "serviceName", //or string
    'Date' => '2015-06-06'
);
echo $res = preg_replace_callback('/{{(.*?)}}/', function($m) use ($arr) {
       return isset($arr[$m[1]]) ? $arr[$m[1]] : $m[0]; // If the key is uknown, just use the match value
    }, $s);
// => Hello Mr/Mrs customerName. You have subscribed for serviceName at 2015-06-06.
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/B7acCt).

The `$m[1]` refers to what has been captured by the `(.*?)`. I guess this pattern is sufficient for the current scenario (does not need unrolling as the strings it matches are relatively short).

Comment: Thank you. This is what i was looking for.

Comment: I'd suggest `return isset($arr[$m[1]]) ? $arr[$m[1]] : '';` in case there are some tags not registered in the dictionary.

Comment: @Amarnasan: Yes, a good suggestion. If the expected behavior is to just remove unknown tags, this will work. Ivo, please check if this is the expected behavior, and I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes I implemented that of course. Even I made it like this:

return isset($arr[$m[1]]) ? $arr[$m[1]] : '{{'.$m[1].'}}'; So if there is no match it will return the {{key}} to be known that the given key is not proper

Comment: I suggest just using `$m[0]` that stands for the whole matched text. In the example string, I added `{{I_DONT_KNOW_IT}}`, and it is output as is since there is no corresponding key in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a regex for that, you can do it with a simple replacement function if you change a little the array keys:

```
$corr = array(
    'Name' => $customerName, //or string
    'Service' => $serviceName, //or string
    'Date' => '2015-06-06'
);

$new_keys = array_map(function($i) { return '{{' . $i . '}}';}, array_keys($corr));
$trans = array_combine($new_keys, $corr);

$result = strtr($yourstring, $trans);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php

$str = "Hello Mr/Mrs {{Name}}. You have subscribed for {{Service}} at {{Date}}.";

$arr = array(
    'Name' => 'some Cust', //or string
    'Service' => 'Some Service', //or string
    'Date' => '2015-06-06'
);

$replaceKeys = array_map(
   function ($el) {
      return "{{{$el}}}";
   },
   array_keys($arr)
);

$str = str_replace($replaceKeys, array_values($arr), $str);

echo $str;
```